# Breaker panel for exterior post light is permanently tripped. It will not turn on

Tags: circuit-breaker

My post light began tripping my breaker this spring.  Eventually, the breaker began tripping immediately when switching on.  Now it will not even engage in the on position.  I replaced the breaker but no luck.  I disconnected the lamp and photocell but still no luck.  I can't find damage to the electric line feeding the post nor at the entrance point of the house.

Comment: Somehow, somewhere, you've got a dead short that's causing the breaker to immediately trip. When you disconnected the lamp, did you properly terminate the wires so they weren't touching anything? Have you checked every other device on this circuit to ensure there are no loose connections elsewhere?

Comment: If no damage at each end, I bet there is damage in between.  Try the breaker but without the wire/s connected to the breaker.  It should switch on.

Comment: If you were just flipping the breaker back on each time to see if it would stay on, then it might be possible you damaged the bus bar the breaker fits on also.

Comment: Is this a plain breaker or AFCI or GFCI? If it is not a plain breaker, do you know what type of trip it is?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the breaker is an appropriate one for your panel? The breaker _must_ be approved for the panel or you'll cause damage to both.

Comment: @VtC again, let's give a new person some time to [edit] his question with some pics of the panel, breaker in question and wiring at both ends before we close this. It's only been an hour - not everybody _lives_ in SE!

Comment: OP please [edit] your question to add detail. Note you need to do this from the same device and web browser you asked your question on -- if you want to device-hop, then on that original browser, [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) to tie it to a username/password or link it to Google or Facebook login.

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure that the post light is the only device on this circuit, you can check if there is a short circuit in the power line to the lamp post.

Since you're able to get into the panel and change circuit breakers, and have disassembled the lamp post, you can check for a short between the power and neutral or ground wires. You'll need a volt/ohm meter.

At the circuit panel, with the power wire for the lamp disconnected from the circuit breaker, test voltage between the power wire to the neutral bar in the panel (carefully). There should be no voltage, because the wire is disconnected from the breaker. You're checking that the wire isn't also cross-connected to other live circuits. If you see no or very low voltage on the meter, proceed.

Make sure the lamp post end of the power wire is also completely disconnected from any parts of the lamp. Confirm again that voltage is 0 Volts.

Now, switch the volt/ohm meter to ohms, and check resistance between the completely-disconnected lamp post power wire and the neutral bar. If there is a short, you'll see a low number resistance. If there is no short, the resistance will show infinite on the meter. You can do the same test at the lamp post, between power and neutral and the ground line or lamp post body after you've ensured that the power wire at the circuit panel is securely bent away from any possibility of touching live power (capping it with a wire nut is probably a good idea). You may have to jiggle the power wire around a bit at both ends to see if this short might be an intermittent connection that depends on vibration or temperature change to come close enough to connect.

If you have infinite resistance, there is probably no short in the power circuit between the panel and the post, and the cause of the circuit breaker trip may be something else. If you have a low resistance, you have a short in the power wires, and you'd need to replace the wires to the lamp post.